# TypeScript omitted type parameter with default type only being respected when another preceding type parameter is passed

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In this first example, the compiler does not complain when creating a new object of class `Foo`.

```
class Foo<Options extends number[] = (1 | 2 | 3)[] > {
  constructor(
    public options: Options,
    public option: Options[number]
  ) {}
}

new Foo([4, 5], 1);
```

If I now add another type parameter before `Options` and then pass a type for that preceding type parameter, the compiler correctly complains ([screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMMi3.png)).

```
class Foo<Unused, Options extends number[] = (1 | 2 | 3)[] > {
  constructor(
    public options: Options,
    public option: Options[number]
  ) {}
}

new Foo<any>([4, 5], 1);
```

I would expect the first example to behave the same as the second. In the second example, the compiler correctly complains that the first passed constructor argument is not assignable to the default `Options` type `(1 | 2 | 3)[]`. Why does merely passing `any` as the `Unused` type parameter suddenly yield the desired behavior? Why does it not work as expected in the first example?

Comment: But in my understanding, the compiler does not infer anything in the first example. I do not understand why in the first example the default for the type parameter is not respected.

Comment: It definitely does infer in the first example, so your understanding is incorrect. The only time you get defaults is if inference fails, or if you manually specify preceding type arguments. There are no preceding type arguments in the first case, so it’s inferred. Maybe if there were some syntax like `new Foo<>` with an empty type argument you could get a default that way, but there is none.

Comment: So in the first example the inferred type is actually `number[]` and not `(4 | 5)[]`?

Comment: Maybe I made a false assumption, because my initial goal was to limit `option` to one of `options`, but when omitting the `Options` type parameter, its inferred type based on `options` is not narrowed down to the union of the elements in `options`. I don't know why I made that assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to call/construct a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function/class.  You can either explicitly specify type arguments like `foo<X>(x)` or `new Foo<X>(x)` or `bar<X, Y>(z)`, using the `<`⋯`>` syntax; or you can leave off the type arguments like `foo(x)` or `new Foo(x)` or `bar(z)`, without the `<`⋯`>`.

If you explicitly specify any type arguments, then those will be used.  If some of the type parameters have [default type arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) and you leave out type arguments, then the defaults will be used.

On the other hand, if you don't specify any type arguments, then all the type arguments will be *inferred*.  The defaults will *not* be used in this case (unless inference fails completely).

You might hope to be able to "mix and match" this functionality, specifying some type arguments, while having some other ones inferred, or get defaults instead of inference, but this is not currently possible.  There's a longstanding open GitHub at [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) asking for such abilities, but it's not part of the language now.

---

Given that, we can explain the behavior you're seeing. First:

```
class Foo<Options extends number[] = (1 | 2 | 3)[] > {
  constructor(
    public options: Options,
    public option: Options[number]
  ) {}
}

new Foo([4, 5], 1);
```

You have not specified a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument for `Options`.  There is no `<`⋯`>`.  So you get inference.  `Options` is inferred from the argument `[4, 5]` for `options`, and it is inferred as `number[]`.  (It is out of scope for this question to go into why it is `number[]` and not `(4 | 5)[]` or `[4, 5]` or anything else.)

Next:

```
 class Foo<Unused, Options extends number[] = (1 | 2 | 3)[] > {
  constructor(
    public options: Options,
    public option: Options[number]
  ) {}
}

new Foo<any>([4, 5], 1);
```

You have specified `any` for the `Unused` type parameter, so no inference happens.  The `Options` type argument takes its default type of `(1 | 2 | 3)[]`, and thus you get an error because `[4, 5]` is not assignable to `(1 | 2 | 3)[]`.

---

Whether or not any of this counts as "desired behavior" depends on the use case, but it seems like according to some of the comments it's probably not actually desirable, and the inference-vs-default issue was masking that.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?pretty=false&ts=5.3.3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBJBvAUEp8A2IUUSAYgPZkA88ZwUALkgPIz0CWtxEAHvRMABNiwAK5gARhABOAbQC6APgzYcuTvSkj49MlIAUK1UhgjxeNvCRlWHOgC5mNzgBpDqk2YtWnwBy3acMqIS0nJuAJQYSAC+KrEqwBAA7qQUejIALM5IAKxy2QCM4QDcmPGgkLAIyABCyjj4hMTkVACqolAQAtn+tly8-EJIwZKyckgAvEh6BUgAPkgATPNIAMzh8kpYRjR0Glo6+m44HuaW1gH2jpdQrkYnpmfel34+UEFio2FGkegxcZgEslUlQQMAAJ4KdJZXL5JBFUrRIA)

Comment: I think I do understand now. Btw thanks for that playground link where you introduced `Options` to be a [`const` Type Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters). I wasn't aware of this feature.